# Hyperledger Fabric: I would like to test the functionality of Anchor Peer, how can it be done?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I would like to understand and test the functionality of Anchor Peer in the Hyperledger Fabric Network.

As per the documentation

> Anchor Peer:Used to initiate gossip communication between peers from
>   different organizations. The anchor peer serves as the entry point for
>   another organization’s peer on the same channel to communicate with
>   each of the peers in the anchor peer’s organization.

Does that mean, if I bring down the Anchor peer of ORG2 the transactions to peers of ORG2 will NOT be updated?

I have tried to do this practically. I have a channel mychannel where 2 peers from ORG1 and 2 peers of ORG2 participate. Where peer0 of both ORG are Anchor peers.

I brought down both Anchor peers and did transactions on peer1 of both org I expected that the changes might not reflect in other ORG but it does...

```
So my Question is: What is the basic role of Anchor peer? And How can I test it?
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3):

An anchor peer is just an entry in the config block of a channel, that helps peers of different organizations to know each other.

Once they learned about each other's endpoints - the anchor peer has no further use, unless the peers crash and are restarted.